# Any ideas on how we can convert a model from huggingface (transformers library )to tensorflow lite?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, tflite

I want to convert CamembertForQuestionAnswering model to tensoflow lite
i download it from huggingface platform, because when i want to save the model locally it gives me the model with 'bin' format.

- when i try to convert the model it gives me this error : AttributeError: 'CamembertForQuestionAnswering' object has no attribute 'call' by using tf_model.h5 file.
- Also i can't load it using : tf.keras.models.load_model() it gives me : ValueError: No model config found in the file at <tensorflow.python.platform.gfile.GFile object at 0x7f27cceb1810>.
- when i want to save the transformers model locally it gives me the model with 'bin' format, so i download it from the platform.